# The path was not easy?

Tags: grammar

I wanted to say that "English is my second language so for me to get in to this academy was hard" 
Would you be able to say the path (way?) to accomplish my goal was not easy? (Like it was a long way to accomplish my goal.)

I think there is a better way of saying this but I cannot remember.

Comment: You could say "the journey to my goal was hard" or "a hard slog" (idiomatic).

Answer (score 0):

"It was not/has not been an easy path/road [to ...]" is a common phrase.  "An easy road" is more common than "an easy path", I think.

For what you want to say, "It's not been an easy road to reach my goal, but ..." sounds natural.